# flexbox | flex item being pushed out of containing div (off screen)

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using the [flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to style a list of past tasks. The task description and the time are always going to be of very variable lengths.

Everything looks great until a task description is entered which is long enough to wrap onto a second line and then the 'time' item (on the far right of the screen) is pushed slightly to the right - off the screen - hiding some of the content.

You can see the short description displays perfectly below, but the long one pushes what should be '00:08' off the screen AND the task description moves to the left as well!!

[image: flex-item-pushed-off-screen-chrome]

**Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmdav1eg/) for the code** (which is below as per Stackoverflow's rules).
If you *resize the pane containing the result* the '00:08' doesn't fall off the page but it does clearly move too far to the right.

The above screenshot is in Chrome or Safari (the two browsers I was using) when shrinking the width of the window until the description wraps onto a second line.

**I would like everything to display as per the first (short description) line if possible!** And also to understand why this is behaving as it currently is.

*P.S. I have tried using floats and also using a table display layout but both of these techniques caused quite a few bugs, mostly because of the variable length content (so please don't suggest these as alternatives :)).*

```css
ul {
      margin:0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #tasklist{
      width: 100%;
    }
    
      .task-one-line{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-item: baseline; /*flex-end*/
        display: -webkit-flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction:row;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -webkit-align-item: baseline; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        width: 100%;
      }
    
        .task-one-line i{
          width:1.5em;
          padding: 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em;
          /*border: 1px solid green;*/
        }
    
          span.task-desc{
            flex-grow: 5;
            -webkit-flex-grow: 5;
            text-align:left;
            padding: 0.3em 0.4em 0.3em 0.4em;
            /*border: 1px solid red;*/
          }
         
          span.task-time{
            flex-grow: 1;
            -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
            flex-basis:4em;
            -webkit-flex-basis:4em;
            text-align:right;
            padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em;
            /*border: 1px solid blue  ;*/
          }
```

```html
    <ul id="tasklist">
        <li class="task-one-line">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
            <span class="task-desc">And a short one</span>
            <span class="task-time">00:01</span>
        </li>
        <li class="task-one-line">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
            <span class="task-desc">Here's a super long long long long long long description that might wrap onto another line</span>
            <span class="task-time">00:08</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really, you only want the text content to have a flexible width (the time and the icon should have a fixed width and not shrink). This could be pretty easily accomplished with tables, absolute positioning, or flexbox.

Here's the flexbox that you need to know:

```
.task-time: flex: 1 0 4em
.task-one-line i.fa { flex: 0 0 auto; }
```

```css
ul {
      margin:0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #tasklist{
      width: 100%;
    }
    
      .task-one-line i.fa { flex: 0 0 auto; }
      .task-one-line{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-item: baseline; /*flex-end*/
        display: -webkit-flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction:row;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -webkit-align-item: baseline; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        width: 100%;
      }
    
        .task-one-line i{
          width:1.5em;
          padding: 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em;
          /*border: 1px solid green;*/
        }
    
          span.task-desc{
            flex-grow: 5;
            -webkit-flex-grow: 5;
            text-align:left;
            padding: 0.3em 0.4em 0.3em 0.4em;
            /*border: 1px solid red;*/
          }
         
          span.task-time{
            flex: 1 0 4em;
            -webkit-flex: 1 0 4em;
            text-align:right;
            padding: 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em;
            /*border: 1px solid blue  ;*/
          }
```

```html
<ul id="tasklist">
        <li class="task-one-line">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
            <span class="task-desc">And a short one</span>
            <span class="task-time">00:01</span>
        </li>
        <li class="task-one-line">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
            <span class="task-desc">Here's a super long long long long long long description that might wrap onto another line  long long long long long long description that might wrap onto another line</span>
            <span class="task-time">00:08</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Adam - this works in that the timer now shows on the screen but it backs the text up into the icon, causing an ugly formatting issue whereby the text is misaligned from one line to the next: http://imgur.com/VtsaujO        Do you know of a way to prevent this? (Just a quick note, the time has to be flexible as it can go up to 9 characters but as low as 5!). Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Do you have a link to your code? This line: `.task-one-line i.fa { flex: 0 0 auto; }` should have prevented that specific issue from happening. In Safari, you need to prefix your flexbox code so `display: flexbox` becomes `display: -webkit-flexbox` and `flex: 0 0 auto` becomes `-webkit-flex: 0 0 auto` (and so on).

Comment: Hooray! It would appear my cache didn't clear properly so I cleared it 3 times and it now seems to work as expected. Fantastic, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue, I created a pen with the fix:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRBMMm

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.a {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.b {
  flex: 1;
  background: #ffbaba;
  min-width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.c {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="a">1st div</div> 
  <div class="b">HELLO2HELLO2 HELLO2HELLO2 2222 HELLO2HELLO 22222</div>
  <div class="c">3rd div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

My general rule for flex is flex the containers you want to flex and don't flex the ones you do not. I would do the following to the time container.

`span.task-time {flex: none;}`

Comment: Thanks Eugene, but as I mentioned, the time will always be a variable length as it can include hours and therefore be anywhere between 5 and 9 characters. Good advice though!

Comment: I updated your fiddle with the suggestion mentioned above. Flex none will treat the div as an inline-block element. It will grow according to its content. http://jsfiddle.net/aestheticdrift/pmdav1eg/2/