# Buttons outside of his flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

*Hello, i've lost half of my hair in 2 days, sorry for my english :)*

If you resize the window **the buttons in #header go outside of his container**.

*Here is the code:*

```css
#root {
  background: grey;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#header {
  background: red;
  
  align-self: stretch; /* fill in main-axis */
  flex: 0 0 65px; /* fixed height */
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="header">
    <button>PUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUSH</button>
    <button>BYE.</button>
  </div>
  <----- resize me ---->
</div>
```

I think the problem is **#root.width is leaded by window/body.width** ?

*I have a solution with **min-content**:*
`#root { min-width: min-content; ... }`*, but i don't want use this value.*

**How configure #root correctly acting as a good and beautiful container for my layout ?**

Here is a codepen for playing: [https://codepen.io/papawa/pen/NLKbKR](https://codepen.io/papawa/pen/BOjdRZ)

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap;` ?

Comment: For #root ? This doesn't work as expected, the #root width isn't equal to its content .

Comment: not root but header

Comment: The "push" button still go outside of the container. I would like to not wrap my content #header. I will change my question, the idea is getting the same result as #root { ... min-width: min-content } without this value because this still experimental.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flexbox | flex item being pushed out of containing div (off screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638449/flexbox-flex-item-being-pushed-out-of-containing-div-off-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply there is no problem, it's a logical result, unless you decide what do  you expect to get in a smaller screens then that's what you will get and the reason is that you have a button with a long 'one word text' and the solution to fix this is just by wrapping the text itself and that's how you do it:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

or

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Here's the overall result:

```css
 #root {
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items:center;
      background:grey;
      overflow:hidden;

    }

    #header {
      align-self:stretch;
      flex: 0 0 65px;
      
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      
      background: red;
      padding: 10px;
}
.btn{
  width: 50vw;
  
  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="header">
    <button class="btn">PUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUSH</button>
    <button>BYE.</button>
  </div>
  <---- resize me ---->
</div>
```

FOR FURTHER READING: [Handling Long Words and URLs (Forcing Breaks, Hyphenation, Ellipsis, etc)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

Comment: Thank you, that's clarify what I encountered